# Perl using 'map' to rewrite these codes

Tags: perl

Can I use 'map' or some similar function to make the codes simpler?

```
# $animal and @loads are pre-defined somewhere else.

my @bucket;

foreach my $item (@loads) {

    push @bucket, $item->{'carrot'} if $animal eq 'rabbit' && $item->{'carrot'};

    push @bucket, $item->{'meat'} if $animal eq 'lion' && $item->{'meat'};

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean that `$item{'food'} = 'carrot'` when `$animal eq 'rabbit'`. Or do you have a key for each type of food for each animal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
%foods = ( 'lion' => 'meat', 'rabbit' => 'carrot');

# ...

foreach my $item (@loads) {
    push @bucket, $item->{$food{$animal}} if $item->{$food{$animal}};
}
```

Comment: If you really wanted, you could replace the loop using `grep` and  `map`: `@bucket = grep {$_} map {$_->{$food{$animal}} @loads`; but I'd go with the above.

Comment: Driving the code over a hash is a good solution.  I think you are missing something, though you don't iterate over a set of animals.

Comment: The equivalent with `map` is `@bucket = map { $_->{$foods{$animal}} ? $_->{$foods{$animal} : () } @loads`.

Comment: Other equivalent mappish solutions: `grep $_, map $_->{$foods{$animal}}` or even `map { $_->{$foods{$animal}} || () }`.  None of these address the fact that we are only looking at one `$animal`.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be easier to answer authoritatively with a bit more sample data.  As it is I need to make a lot of assumptions.

Assuming:

```
@loads = (
    { carrot => 47, meat => 32, zebras => 25 },
    { carrot => 7,  zebras => 81 },       
);
```

and `@buckets` should look like:

```
@buckets = ( 47, 32, 7 );
```

when `@animals` looks like:

```
@animals = qw/ rabbit lion /;
```

Here's a maptastic approach.  To understand it you will need to think in terms of lists of values as the operands rather than scalar operands:

```
my @animals = qw/ rabbit lion /;
my %eaten_by = (
    lion   => 'meat',
    rabbit => 'carrot',
    mouse  => 'cheese',
);

# Use a "hash slice" to get a list of foods consumed by desired animals.
# hash slices let you access a list of hash values from a hash all at once.
my @foods_eaten = @eaten_by{ @animals };

# Hint: read map/grep chains back to front.
#       here, start with map @loads and then work back to the assignment
my @bucket =
    grep $_,                   # Include only non-zero food amounts
    map @{$_}{@foods_eaten},   # Hash slice from the load, extract amounts of eaten foods.
    map @loads;                # Process a list of loads defined in the loads array
```

Rewritten in a verbose nested loop you get:

```
my @buckets;
for my $item ( @loads ) {
    for my $animal ( @animals ) {
        my $amount = $item{ $eaten_by{$animal} };
        next unless $amount;

        push @buckets, $amount;
    }
}
```

Which one to use?  It all depends on your audience--who will be maintaining the code?  Are you working with a team of Perl hackers featuring 4 of the perl5porters? use the first one.  Is your team composed of one or two interns that come and go with the seasons who will spend 1% of their time working on code of any kind?  Use the second example.  Likely, your situation is somewhere in the middle.  Use your discretion.

Happy hacking!